MySQL storage lower than used disk
We are running MySQL on K8S (GKE) and running out of disk space (800Gb).
When looking in the file system running df
$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb        787G  776G   12G  99% /var/lib/mysql

but when running
ls -lah

the numbers are not even close to 99% disk usage.
Any idea what might cause that?

It needs also place for temp tables, so on crease urgently the diskspace

As nbk notes, temp tables do not show up in ls, but they still take space. MySQL unlinks temp tables as soon as they are created. The storage is released when they  are closed, or if mysqld exits. You might have a lot of queries creating large temp tables. Does the disk usage return to expected levels if you stop mysqld?

@BillKarwin Yes this is probably the case. Is there a way to monitor / see disk usage by unlinked temp tables?

You can query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-innodb-session-temp-tablespaces-table.html.  That will tell you about InnoDB temp tables on disk. A temp table may be small enough that it fits in RAM, and if so, it won't take any disk space.

A database file is a sparse file. Not all portions of the file have been written in.  Most databases (if not all) allocate more space than is actually used, for speed.

df shows you the actual space that it would occupy if it was full.  This is about disk storage.
ls shows you what you the size you of data that has actually been written.  It is what you would red back.  It is focusing on files.

There is a more in-depth discussion here.
In addition to the above (as mentioned in comments) storage is required for temporary files.  My advice would be to, urgently, increase your disk size, before you have a disaster on your hands.

Run this:
du / | sort -nb | tail

to find the largest 10 directories.  Perhaps that will give you some more clues.
(It will take some time and requires use of 'root'.)
(Sort may run out of disk space since it needs a temp table.  If so, we can devise a way to avoid the sort.)
